# IIS 7.5 not serving files with + in the name

Tags: web-server, iis-7.5

IIS isn't serving files with + in the name e.g. `hello+world.txt`

Where would I go to change this?

EDIT:
This worked in IIS6. Would it have been a unique setting there as well?

Answer (score 1):

URL Encoding replaces spaces with + so when this is being consumed by the webserver, the + is being replaced with a space. You should not change this as this is how URL Encoding works.  Don't put plus signs in your filenames.